# Django form problem, Repeating a form n times in one template

Tags: html, django, django-forms

As title

What I want to do is to add a button. After pressing the button, a duplicate form will be added to enter data. Need to add a few pieces of information, just press the button several times!

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use javascript for this.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('add')
let form = document.querySelector('.form')
let forms = document.getElementById('forms')

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clone = form.cloneNode(true)
    forms.appendChild(clone)
});
```

```html
<div id='forms'>
  <form class='form'>
    <input placeholder='Name'>
  </form>
</div>
<button id='add'>Add more!</button>
```

But you can use formsets to repeat the same form multiple times on the same page without the button:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/